# Generating a Connection String in C#

Tags: c#, odbc, connection-string

I'm trying to write an application that will let users connect to an arbitrary database, assuming they have the proper ODBC drivers. However, I'm getting stuck on the connection strings. For any particular database type it's easy to look online and find which keyword/value pairs are required, but is that information accessible from the driver itself?

What I want to do is have the user select the driver they want from a list (generated by SQLDrivers), then generate a form that will prompt them for the keywords necessary to generate the string, so that my application does not need to know about specific ODBC drivers. Is there any way to do this? Or will I have to hard code support for each one separately? Maybe connection strings aren't the way to go, and there's another method I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very simple way to solve this, actually, at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms715433(v=vs.85).aspx.

If you call the ODBC API function SQLDriverConnect with an incomplete connection string (like, for example, one that only contains the Driver keyword) and set the last argument to SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE, it will pop up with a dialog generated by the driver that prompts for any required information that wasn't included, then return the finished connection string once it's closed.

Comment: In case anyone else needs this, more details on how to do this are [here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/odbc32/SQLDriverConnect.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at [`ConnectionStringBuilders`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254947.aspx) and see if they'll be any help.

You can use the following code to enumerate the configurable properties, which would allow you to create your config form.

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

var properties = (from key in builder.Keys.OfType<string>()
                  select key);
```

`properties` contains:

```
Data Source 
Failover Partner 
AttachDbFilename 
Initial Catalog 
Integrated Security 
Persist Security Info 
User ID 
Password 
Enlist 
Pooling 
Min Pool Size 
Max Pool Size 
Asynchronous Processing 
Connection Reset 
MultipleActiveResultSets 
Replication 
Connect Timeout 
Encrypt 
TrustServerCertificate 
Load Balance Timeout 
Network Library 
Packet Size 
Type System Version 
Application Name 
Current Language 
Workstation ID 
User Instance 
Context Connection 
Transaction Binding
```

Comment: I've looked at ConnectionStringBuilders, but it looks like it only contains keywords that have already been added manually, which doesn't help with determining them to begin with. At least that's the way it's being used in the code examples.

Comment: See my latest update. You can enumerate properties from `Keys`; it will not return only the keys you've set.

Answer (score 3):

In 2010 Microsoft released there VS2010 Connection dialog for us little people to use. It is awesome, should do what you want and is freely distributable. The download for the dialog and its source code can be found [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Connection/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3863).

To get you started: once you have compiled the code you will need to include references to `Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI`, `Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.Dialog` and `Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.SqlCeDataProvider`. The dialog is then called like

```
// Initialisation.
DataConnectionDialog dcd = new DataConnectionDialog();
DataConnectionConfiguration dcs = new DataConnectionConfiguration(null);
dcs.LoadConfiguration(dcd);

// Edit existing connection string.
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strExistingConn))    
    dcd.ConnectionString = strExistingConn;

// Launch Microsoft's SqlConnection dialog.
string strSqlFinConn = String.Empty;
if (DataConnectionDialog.Show(dcd) == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // Load tables as test.
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(dcd.ConnectionString))
        connection.Open();
}
dcs.SaveConfiguration(dcd);
return dcd.ConnectionString;
```

If this is not what you want then @HackedByChinese answer looks like the best approach.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Wish I could select both answers to accept. This looks like the simplest solution, but @HackedByChinese will also be very useful if I decide to roll my own.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the good answers already posted you might want to take a look at the ODBC API [SQLBrowseConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).